# how can we implement typehead functionality with AngularJS v1.3.15 and bootstrap ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to use typehead functionality for auto-suggestion with angular 1.3.15?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 3rd party library like

- https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete
- https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead

Comment: have you plunker regarding,  so that I can implement the same in my project.